# Getting break time taken

Tags: javascript

This is my JavaScript function to get a break time taken. I have two times (time_start and time_end). And with these two times, I have to get my break time. (break time hours are 12:00-13:00 and 17:45-18:15). The code below works but it contains a lot of nested `if` and `else`. Is there any method to reduce them?

```
function timesheet(day,week_type,start_time,end_time){
        this.day = day;
        this.week_type = week_type;
        this.start_time = convertTime(start_time);
        this.start_time = (!isNaN(this.start_time)?this.start_time:0);
        this.end_time = convertTime(end_time);
        this.end_time = (!isNaN(this.end_time)?this.end_time:0);
        this.work_start = convertTime("9:00");
        this.work_end = convertTime("17:45");
        this.break_1_start = convertTime("12:00");
        this.break_1_end = convertTime("13:00");
        this.break_2_end = convertTime("18:15");
        //休憩時間を作業の開始時間と終業時間の次第で下の関数からゲットします。

        this.break_time = function(){
            /** 
             *この関数が取った休憩時間を渡します。 
            */
            if(this.start_time>this.end_time){
                return 0;
            }
            else{
                //if strart time is less than or equal to 12
                if(this.start_time<=this.break_1_start){
                    if(this.end_time<=this.break_1_start){
                        return 0;
                    }
                    else if(this.end_time<this.break_1_end){
                        return (0+(this.end_time - this.break_1_start));
                    }
                    else{
                        if(this.end_time<this.work_end){
                            return 1;
                        }
                        else if(this.end_time<this.break_2_end){
                            return (1+(this.end_time - this.work_end));

                        }
                        else{
                            return 1.5;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(this.start_time<this.break_1_end){
                    if(this.end_time<this.break_1_end){
                        return (this.end_time - this.start_time);
                    }
                    else {
                        if(this.end_time<this.work_end){
                            return (this.break_1_end - this.start_time);
                        }
                        else if(this.end_time<this.break_2_end){
                            let break_one = this.break_1_end - this.start_time;
                            let break_two = this.end_time - this.work_end;

                            return (break_one+break_two);
                        }
                        else{
                            let break_one = this.break_1_end - this.start_time;
                            let break_two = this.break_2_end - this.work_end;
                            return (break_two+break_one);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if(this.start_time<this.work_end){
                    if (this.end_time<this.work_end){
                        return 0; 
                    }
                    else{
                        if (this.end_time<this.break_2_end){
                            return (this.end_time-this.work_end);
                        }
                        else{
                            return(0.5);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(this.start_time<this.break_2_end){
                        return (this.break_2_end-this.start_time);
                    }
                    else{
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }   
}
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for examples, and revise the title accordingly.